# How to make a JMenu have Button behaviour in a JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar, jmenu

I was trying to make a JMenu behave like a JButton but I'm having some problems and hopefully someone here can help!

I've added a MenuListener to the JMenu item with this but I cant get the popup menu/focus to leave to enable me to properly click the JMenu repeated times to trigger this function and i was hoping someone could tell me what i'm doing wrong. Thanks.

```
public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e)
        {
            ... // do stuff here code
            JMenu source = (JMenu)e.getSource();
            source.setSelected(false);
            source.setPopupMenuVisible(false);

        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish here.  Why do you want the JMenu to act like a button instead of simply using JMenuItem?

Comment: Maybe provide more of the source code you are working with, so we can see more generally what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not completely sure what you're asking...

But `JMenuBar` inherits from `Container` - if you'd rather add a `JButton` to it than a `JMenu` you can simply call -

```
JMenuBar menuBar = ....
JButton myButton = ....
menuBar.add(myButton);
```

Comment: Ahhhh I didnt realise you could add a JButton to a JMenuBar... Thanks soo much

Comment: the button looks different from a JMenu.

Answer (score 1):

This code sample runs in eclipse, Again concerned about how you are using it?

```
public class MyMenuFrame extends JFrame {


    public MyMenuFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        super("My Frame");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 300);
        Container pane = this.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pane.add(new JLabel("Hi there"), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        this.setVisible(true);
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");

        menu.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println("a");

            }

            @Override
            public void menuDeselected(MenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println("a");

            }

            @Override
            public void menuCanceled(MenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println("a");

            }
        });
        menubar.add(menu);
        this.setJMenuBar(menubar );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyMenuFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I think I might have a solution. I stumbled accross this problem in one of my apps, and found a workaround. Try using a JMenuItem instead of a JMenu. It will have the same L&F as a JMenu when you attach it to a JMenuBar. The only thing you have to do is set the size of your new "button", as your Layout Manager (even if you have not set one) will resize this component based on its own rules:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2000/jw-0922-javatraps.html

The way to do it is found under that link (if you feel uncomfortable clicking on the link, google for "setsize doesnt work" - it will be the in the top ten results). If you do not set the size properly, your new "button" will fill up the remaining space of your JMenuBar.

try this code:

```
menuItem.setMinimumSize(someMenu.getSize());
menuItem.setPreferredSize(someMenu.getSize());
menuItem.setMaximumSize(someMenu.getSize());
menuItem.setActionCommand("ActionText");
```

setActionCommand() method will set an action command, so that when you click your new "button" this will be the action command passed by the action event argument to the action performed method, so that you can easily identify it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to determine what you're trying to do here.  But I don't think you are properly using JMenu.

A JMenu is the object that represents a Menu.  It is separate from the menu bar (JMenuBar) and from the menu item (JMenuItem).  A JMenuBar usually contains multiple JMenus (File, Edit, etc) which in turn contain multiple JMenuItems (New, Open, Close).  The JMenuItems are what is clicked and "acts like a button" in the menu.

To get a menu item to act like a button, simply add it to the menu.  For example:

```
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
JMenuItem newChoice = new JMenuItem("New");
newChoice.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        newHasBeenSelected();
    }
});
fileMenu.add(newChoice);
```

If you're trying to create a pop-up menu, you need to use JPopupMenu instead of JMenu, and you don't need a JMenuBar.  Here are the Java tutorials on menus: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

And here are the Java docs for [JMenuBar](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuBar.html), [JMenu](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuBar.html), [JPopupMenu](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html), and [JMenuItem](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html).

If you edit your question and give a more detailed explanation of what you're doing I might be able to give more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I decided to investigate this a bit more and The following is the reslut and appears to act just like a JButton but appears like a jmenu on a jmenubar. Code below. (note just adding an actionListener to a JMenu didnt work right which is the reason for the mouselistener. You add an actionListener to the menubutton just like a normal button and as long as you dont add any menuitems to the menubutton (which technically you could) it will appear as a JMenu on the JMenuBar but behave like a button.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.EventListener;   
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JMenu;

public class MenuButton extends JMenu {

private boolean startedIn = false;
private ActionListener action;

public MenuButton(String title) {
    super(title);
    removeListeners(this);
    this.addMouseListener(new MenuButtonListener());

}

public MenuButton(ImageIcon icon) {
    super();
    removeListeners(this);
    this.addMouseListener(new MenuButtonListener());
    this.setIcon(icon);
}

public void addActionListener(ActionListener a) {
    action = a;
}
    //we need to remove all the listeners already associated with a JMenu. If we do
//not do this, then it will not behave as expected because some mouseclicks are eaten 
//by these listeners. There is no easy way to do that, the following method is a 
//workaroundprovided in the java bug database. 
static private void removeListeners(Component comp) {
    Method[] methods = comp.getClass().getMethods();
    for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
        Method method = methods[i];
        String name = method.getName();
        if (name.startsWith("remove") && name.endsWith("Listener")) {

            Class[] params = method.getParameterTypes();
            if (params.length == 1) {
                EventListener[] listeners = null;
                try {
                    listeners = comp.getListeners(params[0]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // It is possible that someone could create a listener
                    // that doesn't extend from EventListener. If so, ignore
                    // it
                    System.out.println("Listener " + params[0]
                            + " does not extend EventListener");
                    continue;
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < listeners.length; j++) {
                    try {
                        method.invoke(comp, new Object[] { listeners[j] });
                        // System.out.println("removed Listener " + name +
                        // " for comp " + comp + "\n");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Cannot invoke removeListener method "
                                        + e);
                        // Continue on. The reason for removing all
                        // listeners is to
                        // make sure that we don't have a listener holding
                        // on to something
                        // which will keep it from being garbage collected.
                        // We want to
                        // continue freeing listeners to make sure we can
                        // free as much
                        // memory has possible
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // The only Listener method that I know of that has more
                // than
                // one argument is removePropertyChangeListener. If it is
                // something other than that, flag it and move on.
                if (!name.equals("removePropertyChangeListener"))
                    System.out.println("    Wrong number of Args " + name);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MenuButtonListener extends MouseAdapter {

    boolean within = false;
    boolean pressed = false;


    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        MenuButton.this.setSelected(true);
        pressed = true;
        //System.out.println("pressed");
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("released");
        MenuButton.this.setSelected(false);
        if (action != null && within && pressed) {
            action.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this,
                    ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null));
            MenuButton.this.setSelected(false);
        }
        pressed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        within = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        within = false;
    }
}
}
```