# How to add a JButton on my JMenuBar?

Tags: java, applet, jmenubar

For a assignment I am to modify an existing java applet.
I'm trying to get a JButton (or a clickable JMenu) on my JMenuBar.
There are a few menu's and one of them should be usable as a button.

I found the same question several times but the winning answer stated that it would be "bad" and should still be an item in a JMenu.
While this is a possibility I really would prefer otherwise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this post that (I think) is related to your question:

[How to make a JMenu have Button behaviour in a JMenuBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456501/how-to-make-a-jmenu-have-button-behaviour-in-a-jmenubar)

Is this wat you are trying to accomplish?

Good luck!