# Learning Java GUIs -

Tags: java, swing

I'm learning GUI programming in java, and trying to modify an existing programme to add a new menu bar at the top of the frame.

The main method is below. The MainPanel class extends JPanel and contains the main components of the programme (a basic game).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sokuban");
        MainPanel panel = new MainPanel();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

I'm not sure if I should add a new JPanel, add it to the JFrame, and then within that add buttons? Or create a JMenuBar, within the existing panel, or frame, and then use BorderLayout.NORTH to arrange it?

Just playing around with things I found on google, I've tried the following snippets separately (haven't put all code in):

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
```

---

```
frame.add(new Button("Button"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

---

```
panel.BorderLayout.SOUTH;
```

---

```
  JPanel frame2 = new JPanel();
    window.add(frame2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JButton b1 = new JButton();
    frame2.setSize(500,500);     
    b1.setSize(400,400);
    b1.setVisible(true);
    b1.setText("Button");
    frame2.add(b1);
    frame2.setVisible(true);
```

I can't figure out which direction I should be going in. Any pointers v much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at [How to Use Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).

Answer (score 1):

First : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html :)
This is quite easy tutorial of JMenuBar. :)
And if you one want to only a button on JBarMenu :
[How to make a JMenu have Button behaviour in a JMenuBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456501/how-to-make-a-jmenu-have-button-behaviour-in-a-jmenubar)

Comment: Thank you so much - that link helped immensely!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that, check this out it's what you're looking for

This link is for a JMenuBar 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MenuBar.html

This link is for a JMenu https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html

This link is for a JMenuItem 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html

You don't need a new JFrame to create a menu, you can use the JMenuBar();

```
JMenuBar myMenu = new JMenuBar(); 
//The above snippet does not create or add menus it's simply the container that holds them

JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File"); // This will create a menu named file

JMenuItem openChoice = new JMenuItem("Open"); /* This will create an option under 
the fileMenu named open*/

//To Actually add these things you would do this
  setJMenuBar(myMenu);
  myMenu.add(fileMenu); // This adds fileMenu to the menubar
  fileMenu.add(openChoice); // This adds openChocie to the JMenu named fileOption
```

Now the above code was a very basic example as to how to setup a menu I would sugesst following the code I outlined here and as you learn to improve upon this as this is just a starting point for you!

Comment: Thank you so much! Have just managed to create (a very basic!) one :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure if I should add a new JPanel, add it to the JFrame, and then within that add buttons? Or create a JMenuBar, within the existing panel, or frame, and then use BorderLayout.NORTH to arrange it?

Here are some personal experience that I can share with you:

I will usually plan the appearance of my user interface first (Either on paper on in my mind). After that, decide a suitable ***layout manager*** for the container.

I can have nested panels with more than 1 layout if the UI is complicated.

But ultimately, I will usually have a main panel which hold every other components (subpanels / buttons / textFields..).

Add the main panel into the JFrame. (You can have a customized JPanel, and we rarely need a customized JFrame).

---

**As for the menu bar:**

- Add JMenuItem to JMenu
- Add JMenu to JMenuBar
- Add JMenuBar to the Frame using `frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);`

The following image should help you in understanding of the hierarchy:

[image]